# Playing the URL using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using the code below to play the local movie file `Movie.m4v` in iPhone using the 
`MPMoviePlayerController` and which works fine.

Now I have placed the same file into my online server `mobile.sample.com/Downloads/video/Movie.m4v`. I want to know how I can play that movie using the above URL in the iPhone (not using the `uiwebview`).

How can I accomplish this? Looking for your thoughts. Thanks for any help.

---

```
- (void) readyPlayer
{
    mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

  if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
  {
    // Set movie player layout
    [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [mp setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                       selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                       name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                       object:nil];
    }  
  else
  {
    // Register to receive a notification when the movie is in memory and ready to play.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                         selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                         name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification 
                         object:nil];
  }
NSLog(@"ready");
  // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                        selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                        object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See either watch online or download the data you are anyway going to consume network bandwidth. If you are not using `UIWebView` then you can do either of the following:

1. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use (Basically handle
   the http stream)
2. Download the movie in your application data and then play it. Put
   your own logic of removing it later. Big downside of this is that if
   movie os of large size then you may fail to download it as you app
   gets a limited disk space on iOS device.

Comment: thanks for the reply. just for my learning i want to play a online url inside my iphone app...can you pls help me on this